Flutter Error. Unhandled Exception: HiveError: Cannot write, unknown type: Settings. Did you forget to register an adapter?
I am developing an application in which it is necessary to save user metrics locally in the settings window. I decided to use Hive for this purpose. Generated and registered the adapter. I opened the box, I'm trying to use .put, but I get an error:
E/flutter (19700): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: HiveError: Cannot write, unknown type: Settings. Did you forget to register an adapter?
E/flutter (19700): #0      BinaryWriterImpl.write (package:hive/src/binary/binary_writer_impl.dart:338:9)
E/flutter (19700): #1      BinaryWriterImpl.writeFrame (package:hive/src/binary/binary_writer_impl.dart:282:9)
E/flutter (19700): #2      StorageBackendVm.writeFrames.<anonymous closure> (package:hive/src/backend/vm/storage_backend_vm.dart:128:31)
E/flutter (19700): #3      ReadWriteSync.syncWrite.<anonymous closure> (package:hive/src/backend/vm/read_write_sync.dart:26:41)
E/flutter (19700): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19700): #4      _AsyncCompleter.complete (dart:async/future_impl.dart:41:3)
E/flutter (19700): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19700): #5      BoxImpl._writeFrames (package:hive/src/box/box_impl.dart:88:7)
E/flutter (19700): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (19700): 

My code:
Main.dart
import 'package:diabet_diary/app.dart';
import 'package:diabet_diary/features/Diary/widgets/table.dart';
import 'package:diabet_diary/features/Settings/Settings.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

void main() async {
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(DiaryEntryAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(SettingsAdapter());
  runApp(const DiabetDiaty());

  // ignore: unused_local_variable
  final diabetEntryBox = await Hive.openBox<DiaryEntry>('diabet_entry_box');
  // ignore: unused_local_variable
  final settingsBox = await Hive.openBox('settings_box');
}

Settings_screen.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:diabet_diary/features/MyHomePage/widgets/button_style.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';

part 'Settings_screen.g.dart';

final gkMaxController = TextEditingController();
final gkMinController = TextEditingController();
final fchiController = TextEditingController();
final pathController = TextEditingController();
var settings = Settings(gkMax: '', gkMin: '', fchi: '', path: '');
Box settingsBox = Hive.box('settings_box');

const textstile1 = TextStyle(
  color: Colors.black,
  fontSize: 23,
);

@HiveType(typeId: 2)
class Settings {
  @HiveField(0)
  final String gkMax;
  @HiveField(1)
  final String gkMin;
  @HiveField(2)
  final String fchi;
  @HiveField(3)
  final String path;

  Settings(
      {required this.gkMax,
      required this.gkMin,
      required this.fchi,
      required this.path});
}

class TextLeft extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;
  const TextLeft({super.key, required this.text});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: Text(text, style: textstile1));
  }
}

class SettingsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const SettingsScreen({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //settings = settingsBox.get(0);
    gkMaxController.text = settings.gkMax;
    gkMinController.text = settings.gkMin;
    fchiController.text = settings.fchi;
    pathController.text = settings.path;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
            title: const Text('Настройки')),
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Column(children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: 300,
                  child: Column(children: [
                    const TextLeft(text: 'Максимальный нормальный уровень ГК'),
                    TextField(
                      controller: gkMaxController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: const OutlineInputBorder(),
                        hintText: 'Enter a search term',
                      ),
                    )
                  ]),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 300,
                  child: Column(children: [
                    TextLeft(text: 'Минимальный нормальный уровень ГК'),
                    TextField(
                      controller: gkMinController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        hintText: 'Enter a search term',
                      ),
                    )
                  ]),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 300,
                  child: Column(children: [
                    TextLeft(text: 'ФЧИ'),
                    TextField(
                      controller: fchiController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        hintText: 'Enter a search term',
                      ),
                    )
                  ]),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 300,
                  child: Column(children: [
                    TextLeft(text: 'Путь сохранения дневника'),
                    TextField(
                      controller: pathController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                        hintText: 'Enter a search term',
                      ),
                    )
                  ]),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 120),
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                      style: buttonstylediary,
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (gkMaxController.text.isEmpty) {
                          gkMaxController.text = ' ';
                        }
                        if (gkMinController.text.isEmpty) {
                          gkMinController.text = ' ';
                        }
                        if (fchiController.text.isEmpty) {
                          fchiController.text = ' ';
                        }
                        if (pathController.text.isEmpty) {
                          pathController.text = ' ';
                        }
                        settings = Settings(
                          gkMax: gkMaxController.text,
                          gkMin: gkMinController.text,
                          fchi: fchiController.text,
                          path: pathController.text,
                        );
                        settingsBox.put(0, settings);
                      },
                      child: const Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [Icon(Icons.save), Text("Сохранить")])),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ]));
  }
}

Settings_screen.g.dart
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of 'Settings_screen.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// TypeAdapterGenerator
// **************************************************************************

class SettingsAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Settings> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 2;

  @override
  Settings read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return Settings(
      gkMax: fields[0] as String,
      gkMin: fields[1] as String,
      fchi: fields[2] as String,
      path: fields[3] as String,
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, Settings obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(4)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.gkMax)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.gkMin)
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..write(obj.fchi)
      ..writeByte(3)
      ..write(obj.path);
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is SettingsAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}

I need to save the metrics and then use them to output to TextField using controllers.

The problem is solved. Renaming the Settings class to SettingsSave helped. I can't understand why the error appeared in principle.
